# Ajax not working with SSL on IE error code 12019

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, ssl, jqxhr

I am working on a web application built on Java, JSP, Ajax the servers are JBoss with front in Apche 2 server. The application is accessed over the internet. clients are using mostly IE 7, 8, 9 Browsers.

The application was working perfectly before.Recently we applied SSL certificates over the site, after this we started getting complaints from the user that pages where Ajax is applied are not submitting. Normally we call the ajax on submit button and block the page till response is received from the server. we applied loggers and found that the ajax request calls are failed  with ajax **jqXHR error status as 12019**.

We observed that this error is observed by the users where IE (mostly version 8 and 9) is used. the pattern of error is also not same. some time the same user able to submit page who complaint earlier and some time not. i tried best to produce this scenario over my local and development environment but could not.

i google the problem and found something that 12019 error code is a bug of IE. but why it worked before applying the SSL,
and if SSL is not correct why the problem is only at the ajax page why not somewhere else. I cant say users to change the browser.

This driving me crazy for more then a week. Please help me if anyone else has observed and solve this before.

Comment: Any luck with that error?

Comment: Are the SSL certificates ip based or domain based? IE can't handle domain based certificates.

Comment: Try having your users clear their cache.

Comment: Have you tried appending a cache buster to the URLs you're attempting to call through AJAX? Also can you provide the jQuery version and perhaps a sanitized code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure that Ajax requests are always sent using SSL ? Because most browsers disallow active content to be dynamically loaded from HTTP connections on an HTTPS page.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to IE attempting to cache something it shouldnt.

There are 2 options

1. Add no cache headers
   "If-Modified-Since", "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
   "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
2. Append a cache busting parameter
   "x-1&y=2...&ieispoo="+Date.now()

I realize this is an old question, but someone else might benefit from the answer.