# xhr status value 12019 in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, silverlight

I am sending an AJAX request in an app running on IE.

Sometimes xhr return with an error whose status value is 10219

It seems like its not a standard HTTP status code and might be IE specific.

What could be the reasons for this error and how to fix this ?

I am using IE11.

PS: I tried googling for this but could not found anything useful. Also this is an ***silverlight*** applicatoin

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341741/ajax-not-working-with-ssl-on-ie-error-code-12019

Comment: I would like to know more about the reasons for this issue to occur. I just appears at random in IE. Also we run app with X-UA-Compatible meta with IE=5